# add field at run-time : suffer either vtable-cost or cache miss at destructor

Tags: c++, caching, c++14, destructor, vtable

I want to add non-static field to a (fake) class at run-time.

It is useful for decoupling e.g. `systemA.cpp` can add an `int` field to a certain `Data`, while `systemB.cpp` can add `B` and `C` to the same `Data` class.

Because it is a long question, I will discuss about my design, MCVE, its flaw, my approaches, and question respectively.

### Design

In my design, the memory layout is same as normal class.
Here is the diagram :-

[image]

In my use case, the above layout is faster than `int-int-int ... B-B-B ...`.
(I profiled.)

For simplicity, I lock 64 bytes per field.
Users have to register each desired field and their types to my library before use it:-

```
    Ref<int> refInt=addField<int>();  //e.g. systemA.cpp
    Ref<B> refB=addField<B>();        //e.g. systemB.cpp
    Ref<C> refC=addField<C>();
```

My library will count how many fields user want per 1 `Data` instance (it is 3 in this case).

Then, they can allocate some `Data` instances, and access `Data`'s dynamic field.

```
    std::vector<Data> datas=allocate(10);
    refInt.get(datas[0])=8;
```

To delete a `Data`, user **doesn't** have to call any destructor (`B`'s or `C`'s) manually.
^ It is one of the objective.

### Code ([MCVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/102ef39555c39c53))

Here is my code (library-level, simplified) :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
//---- library -----
void* utilAddAddress(void* current,int offset){
    return reinterpret_cast<char*>(current)+offset;
}
int sizePerInstance=0;//accumulate
struct Data{
    void* mem=nullptr;
    Data(void* pmem){mem=pmem;}
};
template<class T>struct Ref{
    int offset=0;
    T& get(Data data){
         return *static_cast<T*>(utilAddAddress(data.mem,offset));
    }
};
template<class T>Ref<T> addField(){
    Ref<T> reff;
    reff.offset=sizePerInstance;
    sizePerInstance+=64;
    return reff;
}
std::vector<Data> allocate(int numInstance){
    void* oNew= ::operator new(static_cast<size_t>( numInstance*sizePerInstance));  
    std::vector<Data> toReturn;
    for(int n=0;n<numInstance;n++){
        toReturn.push_back(Data(utilAddAddress(oNew,n*sizePerInstance)));
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Here is how it can be used :-

```
class B{    };
class C{   
    std::string danger;    
};
int main(){
    Ref<int> refInt=addField<int>(); //offset = 0
    Ref<B> refB=addField<B>();       //offset = 64
    Ref<C> refC=addField<C>();       //offset = 128
    std::vector<Data> datas=allocate(10);
    refInt.get(datas[0])=8;
    //destructor ?????
}
```

## Problem

It works, but I can't find a way to destroy a lot of `Data` instances efficiently.

To destroy a `Data` instance, I must call destructor of every field : `int`, `B` and `C`.
It is possible that some of the fields (e.g. `C`) are not a POD type, so I can't skip this phase.

So far, I found only 2 choices.  (I will assume that every field of every instance is constructed):-

1. Call destructor in this order : `[0]int [0]B [0]C [1]int [1]B [1]C ...`
2. Call destructor in this order : `[0]int [1]int [2]int ... [0]B [1]B ... [0]C [1]C ...`

### 1st choice

Here is a possible way (draft):-

```
std::vector<std::function<......>> deleters;
template<class T>Ref<T> addField(){
    ......
    deleters.push_back([](......){
        static_cast<T*>(......)->~T();
    });
    ......
}
```

To call all destructor appropriately, I will:-

```
for(int n=0;n<10;n++){
    for(int m=0;m<3;m++){
        deleters[m](data[n]);
    }
}
```

I will suffer v-table cost. (I profiled)

### 2nd choice

I will suffer cache miss, as shown in the below image. (I profiled)

[image]

### **Question**

When delete a lot of contiguous `Data`s, how to call all appropriate destructors efficiently?

I don't expect full code.  Rough description/snippet is enough.

**Side note:**

- In real case, it typically allocates ~4000 instances.  `Data` has 30 fields at most.
- The library is in a game engine core.   It support many types e.g. `Data1` `Data2` ...
- As a temporary measure, I drop support non-POD field.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to make a O(1) by leveragenig a custom allocator.

Everything that goes into Data must use the specific allocator, `std::string` is a `typedef` of `std::basic_string<char>`, which again has a default allocator.

```
using CBString = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, CBAllocator<char>>;
```

Now when `Data` is destroyed, just make `CBAllocator` delete all its pools.

You also have the possibility to split the fields in two groups depending on `std::is_trivially_destructible`. either make 2 distinct data or having one with all none `std::is_trivially_destructible` adjacent to improve cache locality. And you can now ignore going through the destructor for the `std::is_trivially_destructible`.